# How can I have objects in second scene be affected by lighting?

Tags: game-engine

I have an FPS, the weapon is a part of the HUD, and I want it to be affected by lighting in scene 1. I can have it be affected by sun and main things, but it wont work when your character moves and there's a spotlight or a point light. How could I make objects in other scenes be affected by lighting in the main level scene?

-I have gotten a great answer but no .blend; therefore, I will ask kindly for another answer.

Place steps, and a gif(Recommended: http://recordit.co/), and post a .blend. Try to avoid python as much as possible. Sorry this might be asking for too much, but the answer is sitting there, just do it. I want it to be the best type, that is, have it be affected even by walls in the first scene. In other words, I want the weapon to be JUST as it would be in the regular scene but another. Thanks!

Comment: Would it work to link the lamps into the second scene? (`Ctrl L` > Link objects to scene)

Comment: Im not sure, but in scene 2 the weapons are still. There are no movements

Comment: Ensure, that your spot light Energy is way higher. Also, ensure your weapon material has good material.

For starter, use a simple 50% gray material (no spec) and try to move it under the sport lights, which aren't showing up , and play with light energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing comes to mind:

Create the same light source in your second scene (weapons scene) at the same origin, with all properties being the same as the light source in the first scene.

Then save the transformation matrix of your camera from the first scene -> inverse the matrix -> and apply it onto the light source in the second scene.

This way the light source in scene2  will move according to the player movement (camera), and will affect the weapons in the correct way.

---

Now, to have even more realism, we would want to stop seeing the light affecting the weapon, when the player is outside the direct reach of the light source. The simplest solution would be, casting a ray from the 8 corners of the bounding box (bbox) of the player, towards the desired light source, if any of them gets to the light source without hitting any obstacle on the way (we assume no transparent objects), than some part of the player is still in the light, so we set a flag, like so: `bool inLight = true`. 
This flag is used in the second scene, and we compute the light affecting the weapon, only if the flag is true...
Now if you like to be even more specific than that you can create a bbox in scene1, in the place where the weapon would be, and do the same procedure. However, I wouldn't bother going into so much detail in a game (keep it lighter), especially in a FPS game.
What I would do to achieve a similar effect for an FPS game is just cast a single ray from some offset from the front of the character (presumably where the weapon would be) and proceed with the check.

---

As for the ray-tracing check, in the case that you do not have a space partitioning algorithm (octree, kd-tree, etc), you would have to check the ray, brute force, against all objects (not very nice, especially in a game), so I suggest at least having a [Bounding Volume Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy) to store the objects in your scene, as that would optimise things, and I strongly recommend using a spacial partitioning algorithm too. However prove that it works first, with the easiest way! **Slow and correct is better than quick and wrong!** Not always true for games though. ;)

Comment: My computer doesn't work as of now but I'm sure this works. I will accept this answer at the end of the bounty unless I get a better answer.

Comment: Well, in theory it should work. However, even if it does it wont be perfect as it wont take into account other objects and thus, being in shadow (if the player is behind a wall - hidden from the main light source, the weapon will still be lit) There are ways around this but it can become quite involved... 
Do let me know if that has worked in the first place, I will edit if i think of a better solution.

Comment: Yeah as I said I don't have my PC right now. It would be nice if you could explain how do do it, even throught walls.

Comment: Can you place a .blend?

Comment: You mean, place a .blend in the 2nd scene? I wouldn't think so. .blend is a project file, hence that would mean you are working on separate projects. Keep them in one place, you can export and import objects or even append objects into a scene, see this thread: http://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8799

Comment: No I would like a .blend as an example, lol.

Comment: I wouldn't be able to help in that manner, at least until the end of the month as I am very busy at the moment. Cannot promise, but will look into it in more depth after that.

Comment: Well whatever you can, I just hope you will. Take your time.

Comment: I believe it has been FAR more than a month, now can you post a .blend? I hope you're not a take the rep. and run, but actually keep the help. That is all I want, a .blend of the result.

Comment: How do I even access "transformation matrix"

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking long, however I don't have the time. I wont be able to do the scene for you. But don't give up on it... if you have specific questions (as the one above) the community here will answer and help you out.

Now to get transformation and the it's inverse all that needs to be done is the following on the active object... 

myInverse = Matrix(bpy.context.object.matrix_world).inverted()
... make sure you use inverted() rather than invert() as the latter will apply the invert matrix to the object, but you want it copied over.

Comment: I don't know how to write python, I have made a lot of progress through complex logic bricks; I thought there is a simple technique for this.

Comment: I don't have much experience with logic bricks (so you might be able to do it with them too). However I suggest you try writing something with python because all that the logic bricks do are 'visualise code' ... if you can rather write it in code it would be much cleaner, and perhaps you would have much more freedom. Checkout a blender python game engine (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuGWRbFrq3bZkOEpQ02Xpww has quite alot)
 Logic bricks and nodes can get very messy once things get complex, something that a code implementation wouldn't have.